# Integrate with given substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've been given the following definite integral:

$$\int_0^{1/2}\dfrac{1}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}dx$$

I've been asked to solve it using the substitution $x = \sin u$.

My attempts are not yielding the right answer. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you get? I think one form of the answer is $1/\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 5):

Under the given substitution, we have $dx = \cos u \, du$ and hence $$\int_{x=0}^{1/2} \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}} = \int_{u=0}^{\pi/6} \frac{\cos u \, du}{(1 - \sin^2 u)^{3/2}} = \int_{u=0}^{\pi/6} \frac{\cos u}{\cos^3 u} \, du = \int_{u=0}^{\pi/6} \sec^2 u \, du.$$

Comment: Thanks! I came to 1/(cosx)^2. Didn't see I could change it to sec^2x.